# Open local files in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm new to JavaScript. I found an example to open local files with javascript on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14446447/javascript-read-local-text-file). After some googling, I'm able to set my [Chrome](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/How-to-run-things-locally) to allow reading local files, and I am then able to run that example. However, I want to return the string `allText` and use it later in my script. But the string become `undefined` outside `readTextFile()`.

There is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23479913/read-local-text-title-line-by-line-store-lines-in-an-array). It seems like it has something to do with the asynchronous feature of `AJAX`. I can barely the understand the jargons at the moment. I just don't see why in this post the third parameter of `XMLHttpRequest.open()` is set to be `true`.

Anyway, below is my current code. I want to use `allText` outside function `readTextFile()`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <script>
        function readTextFile(file)
        {   
            var allText;
            var rawFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
            rawFile.open("GET", file, false);
            rawFile.onreadystatechange = function ()
            {
                if(rawFile.readyState === 4)
                {
                    if(rawFile.status === 200 || rawFile.status == 0)
                    {
                        var allText = rawFile.responseText;
                        alert(allText);
                    }
                }
            }
            rawFile.send(null);
            return allText; // this is the part that goes wrong I think
        }

        t = readTextFile("foo.file");
        document.write(t) // print out "undeifned" instead of the correct answer

    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: you're declaring `allText` twice (that makes two variables with same name but diferent scope), remove the second `var` keyword before your variable. Good luck with JavaScript!

Comment: @SantiagoHernández That's part of it, but it still wouldn't solve the asynchronous fulfillment race condition, and it would still be undefined until the XHR request completes.

Comment: Dang... I spent 2+ hours on this thing. Thank you @SantiagoHernández

Comment: @BrandonAnzaldi although I don't fully understand your concern, this script works now

Comment: Glad to hear it worked! However, on non-local files, or if there's latency in reading local files, the function will return `allText` before it's been defined by `onreadystatechanged`. Since it's local, it may happen more or less instantaneously, and not cause a problem. :) EDIT: Didn't notice the XHR request was in Synchronous mode. :P

Comment: chris not problem!, @BrandonAnzaldi yeah I know it's a bad practice to do sync Ajax requests, but he's learning the basics I'm assuming

Comment: @SantiagoHernández Ahhh, I didn't even notice that the XHR was synchronous initially. I was assuming the problem stemmed from the callback returning out-of-step with the rest of the script. The variable redeclaration was the correct answer to solve the immediate problem! And the async control flow of JS can be a pain to wrap your head around regardless of skill level. It's super easy to wind up in [callback hell](http://callbackhell.com/). :)

Comment: @SantiagoHernández I've also seen comments about using sync AJAX is depreciated. Just curious, what's the "correct" solution?

Comment: a better solution is to do it @BrandonAnzaldi's way

Comment: @SantiagoHernández I guess after changing "false" to "true"?

Comment: @Chris That should be all that you need to do. Or you could remove the third argument entirely since it defaults to `true`.

Comment: cool thanks. I'll mark @BrandonAnzaldi 's answer as accepted after he corrects it

Comment: Should be correct now @Chris. :) Hope I was able to help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is actually most likely a scope issue. Because you're setting allText asynchronously, it's not available immediately after the function returns. In addition, you're reinitializing allText within a function, which messes with the scope of the return regardless.

`rawFile.onreadystatechange` is executed after the function returns. You can either move the execution into the XHR callback, or wrap the function in a promise, which would still require you modify your control flow a bit.

**Move the `document.write`:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <script>
        function readTextFile(file)
        {   
            var allText;
            var rawFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
            rawFile.open("GET", file);
            rawFile.onreadystatechange = function ()
            {
                if(rawFile.readyState === 4)
                {
                    if(rawFile.status === 200 || rawFile.status == 0)
                    {
                        allText = rawFile.responseText;
                        document.write(allText);
                    }
                }
            }
            rawFile.send(null);
        }

        readTextFile("foo.file");

    </script>
</html>
```

**Promisified:**

```
function readTextFile( file ) {
  return new Promise( function ( fulfill, reject ) {

    var allText;
    var rawFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
    rawFile.open( "GET", file );
    rawFile.onreadystatechange = function () {
      if ( rawFile.readyState === 4 ) {
        if ( rawFile.status === 200 || rawFile.status == 0 ) {
          fulfill( rawFile.responseText )
        }
      }
    }
    rawFile.send( null );
  } );
}
readTextFile( "foo.file" )
  .then( function ( t ) {
    document.write( t );
  } );
```

Both of these will ensure that your script doesn't attempt to use allText until it's been returned by the XHR request.

Though as [Santiago Hernández](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4343318/santiago-hern%c3%a1ndez) pointed out, the XHR request is synchronous, and the scope issue was of a different nature than I first assumed. The problem lies in redeclaring the variable within the function, resulting in the one returned to be undefined.

Comment: actually `allText` is being set syncronously, blocking the main thread... and it's completely accesible after `rawFile.onreadystatechange` finishes

Comment: Yup! My bad. I didn't notice the `false` flag for async on the XHR request initially. Credit where credit is due, you had the correct answer :)

Comment: no problem :).. btw the callback hell is truly a hell

Comment: @both of you, sorry for this dumb question I just posted. As Santiago mentioned, it's really just a syntax issue. I was overwhelmed by all the jargon during the debugging. Also, is there a javascript IDE to help me avoid this kind of mistake?

Comment: @Chris It's not a dumb question at all! I didn't even notice the core problem initially. A linter should help you avoid these issues. Whatever editor you're using, there's probably a linter plugin for it :) ES-Lint or JSHint are the two linters that come to mind, and will give you stylistic and syntax hints, plus helping to catch issues you might have otherwise missed. :)

Comment: @BrandonAnzaldi I use notepad++. awesome I'll try it out. Thanks!

Comment: @Chris http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1046810/using-jslint-in-notepad No worries. Happy coding!